# Should I stop indicator animation right before dismissing view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I know it doesn't really matter in terms of resources but In terms of good practice, I have an activity indicator that starts animating somewhere, and when the task is finished, I dismiss the view that contains that activity indicator.
So, because the view is being deallocated it seems redundant to actually tell the activity indicator to stop animating.

So is this code redundant? :

```
  activityIndicator.stopAnimating() // should this be deleted?
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: For best practice and to keep track of each state its good idead to stopAnimating indicator..... but you don't need to do it bcz on dismiss VC will be deallocated and all its elements will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `dismiss` function, it dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller: which removes the `VC` from memory stack and deallocate all the memory of VC and it's elements. So you can remove the `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()` line.